# Defaulted template argument in std::optional constructor

Tags: c++, templates

`std::optional` has the following constructor:

```
template < class U = T >
constexpr optional( U&& value );
```

The question here is: why template parameter `U` is defaulted to type `T`? What happens if simply change constructor to following:

```
template < class U /* = T */>
constexpr optional( U&& value );
```

Comment: Triple backticks are *only* for code blocks, not inline code. Just use one for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's so if you give it an initializer list (which doesn't have a type, so can't infer a type for `U`), it will initialize a `T` temporary.

For example:

```cpp
std::optional<std::vector<int>> opt({1, 2, 3});
// No type deduced for `U`, defaults to `std::vector<int>`

struct X {
    int a, b;
};
std::optional<X> opt({.a = 1, .b = 2});
// Same here
```